# Change the shortcut keys for selecting complete line

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys

Now the shortcut for selecting or highlighting entire line is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>End/Home</kbd>
But I want to change this shortcut to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Arrows</kbd>.
How to change the shortcuts?

Edit:

Is it possible to change the shortcut key to entire system not for one specific application. I think this <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>End/Home</kbd>  is for entire system not for any particular application. Because this shortcut works on every application.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add an application in which you would like to change the shortcut keys. If it is terminal add it in your explanation and add a terminal tag.

Comment: These keyboard shortcuts are defined by the application. How you can change them and whether you can change them fully depends on the application.